# html5 canvas deal with a lot of animated images

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm developing a game  in HTML5 canvas and I'm only using `context.drawImage()` function. 

However, my game uses a lot of cpu when I reach more than 1000 images to draw. How can I deal with this so I can reduce the cpu usage and make the game smooth? How does some existing games like Habbo Hotel do ? (my game is a isometric game)

Comment: instead of calculating 1000 images to draw, calculate 33.333 images to draw (30fps). Nobody animate things that way. you just need to use setInterval, setTimeout or better `requestanimationframe` and just stick with those.

Comment: I'd imagine he means 1000+ images layered on the same frame.

Comment: @moisrex as @canon said I mean 1000+ images on the same frame, of course I'm using `requestanimationframe` :p

Comment: oh, sorry. then it would be good to cache some images into one image for as long as possible. it means use more RAM instead of CPU.

Comment: I don't know habbo but looking at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCATF_Y3VAE), they are far from 1000 images drawn every frame. They do construct the backgrounds, then only ~30 images are drawn on top of that.

Comment: @Kaiido you can put unlimited furniture on any room, and I've seen rooms with more than 1000 animated furniture/objects

Comment: @jeeping they are using layers: they compose once all the layers and draw them all at once + maybe a few ones that hide characters). And they are using really small sprites, unlike you with your big dog image in your previous question.